# I don't know how to select specific items from jsonnified object in my web application using flask

Tags: python, flask, heroku, jsonify

```
response = requests.get(url)
response_json = response.json()
results = response_json['a'][0]
output = results['a_1'] + results['a_2'] + results['a_3']
return jsonify(output)
```

my output
"abcdefg"

what I want
abcdefg

I'm creating a web app using heroku and when I open the web application I want to return the output without "". I mean to display output without "".

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
return output
```

instead of

```
return jsonify(output)
```

Returning a string returns a string without the quotes. Jsonifying returns a representation of JSON.

Comment: Wow.. I did it !! Thank you Abdur-Rahmaan Janhangeer. I thought I should use jsonify in flask but it's not .

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you `^^`. Returning jsonify  is useful in the case of apis as illustrated [here](https://github.com/Abdur-rahmaanJ/shopyo/blob/dev/shopyo/modules/people/view.py#L226)

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot it! ^^; Thank you Abdur-Rahmaan Janhangeer it helped !